# Duplication/export jsreport server

Tags: duplicates, jsreport

I was working with jsreport server on my own environment. Now I would like to deploy it on the real server. Is there any function like export/ or duplicate to make the new server has all config just like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy the whole application directory if your production server has the same OS.

However usually you copy just these assets and then run `npm install`

- dev|prod.config.json
- data
- server.js
- package.json